# Pythonic way to emulate itertools.product in python 2.4

Tags: python, python-itertools, python-2.4

I have a python 3 script that uses `itertools.product`, but I need to be able to run it on a machine that only has python 2.4 installed. Since `itertools.product` is new in python 2.6, I no longer have access to this function.

**How can I emulate `itertools.product` in Python 2.4 in a pythonic way?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with python 2.4, but [per the 2.7 docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.product):

> This function is equivalent to the following code, except that the
>   actual implementation does not build up intermediate results in
>   memory:

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Answer (score 6):

Equivalent code from http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```